# Recoding a nominal variable with multiple categories into a dummy variable

Tags: r

I am trying to condense a party ID seven point scale variable (pid_x) from the ANES 2012 data to a dummy variable (democrat = 1 and republican = 0). This entails removing all missing values and excluding independents (4). I can remove NAs, but how would I filter out independents and properly mutate the new variable? Yes, I am very new to R. Much appreciated!

The code below provides the following error:

"Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `party_id_recode`.
x Can't recycle `..1` (size 2054) to match `..2` (size 3).
i Input `party_id_recode` is `ifelse(pid_x == 1:3, 1, ifelse(pid_x == 5:7, 0))"

```
library(tidyverse)

anesnew <- anes %>%
  na.omit(anes$pid_x) %>%  
  mutate(party_id_recode = ifelse(pid_x == 1:3, 1,
                              ifelse(pid_x == 5:7, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproducible data and expected output would be very useful, but it looks like your `ifelse()` statement hasn't been constructed properly, and could be simplified:

```
anesnew <- anes %>%
  filter(!is.na(pid_x), pid_x != 4) %>%
  mutate(party_id_recode = case_when(pid_x < 4 ~ 1,
                                     pid_x > 4 ~ 0))
```

With the following sample data:

```
anes <- tibble(pid_x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, NA))
```

The results are:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  pid_x party_id_recode
  <dbl>           <dbl>
1     1               1
2     2               1
3     3               1
4     5               0
5     6               0
6     7               0
```